# How are XSD elements combined in an xsd:extension pattern

Tags: xsd, standards

I am working on transforming an XSD to a FrameMaker EDD, and I get stuck on the xsd:extension mechanism. As the W3C description of the XSD standard is really complex, I am hoping one of the XSD experts here can give me a hint about this.

Here are two of the definitions in my original XSD:

```
<xsd:complexType name="basehierarchy">
   <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
     <xsd:element ref="num"/>
     <xsd:element ref="heading"/>
     <xsd:element ref="subheading"/>
   </xsd:choice>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="docContainerType">
  <xsd:complexContent>
    <xsd:extension base="basehierarchy">
      <xsd:choice>
        <xsd:element ref="interstitial"/>
        <xsd:element ref="toc"/>
        <xsd:element ref="documentRef"/>
      </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:extension>
  </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

I need to resolve extensions before I can create my EDD (and accompanying DTD), but I am not sure what the above patterns should result in. I can imagine various options - one would be to inject the choices of the extension into the choice of the base:

```
<xsd:complexType name="docContainerType">
  <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
     <xsd:element ref="num"/>
     <xsd:element ref="heading"/>
     <xsd:element ref="subheading"/>
     <xsd:element ref="interstitial"/>
     <xsd:element ref="toc"/>
     <xsd:element ref="documentRef"/>       
  </xsd:choice>
</xsd:complexType>
```

As a side effect this would cause the @minOccurs and @maxOccurs to be applied to the elements of the extension pattern. Maybe that is OK but I cannot find explicit information about this. Another option for correct extension of the base pattern would be to add the choice from the extension after the choice of the base:

```
<xsd:complexType name="docContainerType">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xsd:element ref="num"/>
      <xsd:element ref="heading"/>
      <xsd:element ref="subheading"/>
    </xsd:choice>
    <xsd:choice>
      <xsd:element ref="interstitial"/>
      <xsd:element ref="toc"/>
      <xsd:element ref="documentRef"/>       
    </xsd:choice>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

And if the second option is the correct one, should the extension come before or after the base elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the recommendation can give you a clue : [XML Schema Part 0: Primer Second Edition, §4.2 Deriving Types by Extension](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#DerivExt), especially this part of the text:

> When a complex type is derived by extension, its effective content model is the content model of the base type plus the content model specified in the type derivation. Furthermore, the **two content models are treated as two children of a sequential group**.